# Dependency issue with SBT

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

i have created a scala library which is having 2 folders, **main** and **test**:[image: srctestfolders]

in an other project i want to import this library.

However, when i try to import it, i am facing an issue.

Indeed if i import the lib with sbt like this :

```
"com.my.lib" %% "mylib" % "1.2.3"
```

i am not able to see mylib methods that are in (mylib) **test** folder

if i add "test" in the dependency

```
"com.my.lib" %% "mylib" % "1.2.3" % "test",
```

i cannot see methods of (mylib) **main** folder anymore.

i have tried with both and only the first one is taken into account

```
"com.my.lib" %% "mylib" % "1.2.3",

"com.my.lib" %% "mylib" % "1.2.3" % "test",
```

I have also tried combinations like this but nothing much

```
"com.my.lib" %% "mylib" % "1.2.3" % "compile,test",
```

Am i doing something wrong? I would like to be able to import all methods of mylib library, both folders main and test.

Thank you

Comment: How are you exporting the library from the first project?

Comment: I have found the answer, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

adding **"test" classifier "tests"** did the trick

```
"com.my.lib" %% "mylib" % "1.2.3",

"com.my.lib" %% "mylib" % "1.2.3" % "test" classifier "tests"
```